# Лямбда выражение как значение по-умолчанию

Tags: c#, lambda

Надо в GetPersons как значение по-умолчанию передать функцию, всегда возвращающую true, хочется сделать лямбда-выражением. Что тут не так?

```
        public IEnumerable<Person> GetPersons(Choise func = x => true)
        {
            foreach (var u in ManageUsers.GetUsers())
            {
                Person person = new Person();
                person.ImportProperties(u);
                if (func(person))
                {
                    yield return person;
                }
            }
        }

        private delegate bool Choise(Person person);
```

Comment: Я бы переписал код как-то так:

    ManageUsers.GetUsers().Select(u => u.Clone()).Where(func);

А вообще, вы бы сделали их read-only и не клонировали.

Comment: Зачем объявлять свой тип данных, если можно использовать тип [Func<T, TResult>][1]:

    Func<Person, bool>


  [1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb549151.aspx

Comment: @Shad: вопрос вкуса. Например, я использую для хранения возраста структуру `Age`, а не `int` -- позволяет избежать случайного ошибочного использования вне позволенной семантики (например, не даёт перемножить два возраста.). Хотя `int` было бы в принципе достаточно. (А вместо `Func<Person, bool>` я бы всё же порекомендовал `Predicate<Person>`.)

Comment: @VladD: Пример со структурой `Age` полностью себя оправдывает - вы обеспечиваете некую безопасность в отношении возраста.

Но в случае с функциями это, помоему, overhead. Ведь что `Choise`, что `Func<Person, bool>` примет входным параметром `Person` и вернёт `bool`. То есть никакой разницы кроме названия типа нету (Тогда уж лучше записать так: `using Choise = Func<int, bool>`).

Соглашусь, однако, что это всё-таки дело вкуса. Дж. Рихтер в своей "CLR via C#" советует использовать Func<> и Action<>, вместо своих типов. и мне почему-то это запомнилось :)

А по поводу `Predicate<Person>` - плюсую

Comment: Насчёт `using Choise = Func<int, bool>` -- хорошая идея! Рихтер голова и монстр.

Comment: >Тогда уж лучше записать так: using Choise = Func<int, bool>

разве это скомпилируется?

    using Choise = System.Func<int, bool>;

Comment: >Создание псевдонима using упрощает определение идентификатора для пространства имен или типа. Правая часть директивы using alias должна всегда быть полным именем, независимо от предшествовавших ей директив using.

[пруф.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/sf0df423.aspx)

Comment: придумали лямбда, теперь куда их только не хотят запихнуть. Вот даже в параметр по умолчанию некоторым хочется)

Comment: @Spectre: спасибо, был не в курсе.

Comment: @Spectre, да спасибо, верная поправка. Однако, она верна только для того случая, когда директива `using` находится на верхнем уровне (т.е. вне namespace'а).

Разбирая директивы в начале файла компилятор ещё не знает в каких namespace'ах искать используемые типы, поэтому в этом случае указание полного имени типа действительно **обязательно**.

Однако ж, в случае, когда `using` написана внутри namespace'а, это **необязательно**. Дойдя до этого места, компилятор успешно обработал внешние директивы `using` и уже сможет определить, что тип `Func<T, TResult>` находится в пространстве имён `System`.

Comment: То бишь, этот незамысловатый код успешно скомпилируется:

    using System;
    
    namespace MyNamespace
    {
     using Choise = Func<int, bool>;
    
     //...
    }

Comment: @semenevx27 Ага, и даже ста лет не прошло. Шустры...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ещё вариант - использовать в качестве значения по умолчанию `null`:

```
public IEnumerable<Person> GetPersons(Choise func = null)
    {
        foreach (var u in ManageUsers.GetUsers())
        {
            Person person = new Person();
            person.ImportProperties(u);
            if ((func ?? (x=>true))(person))
            {
                yield return person;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Нельзя так делать. Выход из ситуации - перегрузка без параметров.